# Sum of the variance of individual element of multinomial distribution

Tags: multinomial-distribution

Suppose I have a multinomial distribution with 10 outcomes and each has prob of 0.1 (i.e. weight of 10%). After each random draw, I can calculate the weight of the sample w1, w2... w10, and I want to calculate the expected deviation from the mean: $E((w_1-0.1)^2 + (w_2-0.1)^2... + (w_10-0.1)^2)$. Somehow I feel like I can reduce it to summing the variance of each individual outcome. But what happen to the covariance term? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution
I am confused and feel I am missing something.

Comment: Deviation from the mean of what? A multinomial outputs an array of frequencies, e.g. across 10 colors.

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith the total deviation from the expected weights of each color, which is 10%: $((1−0.1)^2+(2−0.1)^2...+(10−0.1)^2)$

Comment: Since $w_1,\dots, w_{10}$ are identical, use linearity of expectation to get in terms of only $w_1$. Then, it becomes a binomial problem.